# how to use tc with htb on arch-linux

Tags: networking, arch-linux, tc

I'm trying to use this [tc script](http://www.iplocation.net/tools/traffic-control.php) on my arch box.

Specifically, the first line, roughly equal to `tc qdisc add dev eth0 root handle 1: htb default 3` fails with `RTNETLINK answers: Operation not permitted`

I get another couple of those and a couple `We have an error talking to the kernel`.

I searched around, nobody mentions `tc` depends on another package to use `htb`, I'm using it exactly as specified on the site with `./script.sh start`. Running with sudo gives the same results.

What's the next course of action to use tc with htb on arch linux?

Comment: you need `sudo`.

Comment: I used sudo, it didn't work.

Comment: yeah. its cause im wrong. i followed you link and the suggestion there is to reboot due to kernel upgrades. when your kernel upgrades in arch linux you wind up losing access to most modules because they're not loaded when you do. only those that are in memory stick around. you can symlink the old kernel versions module directory temporarily to the new one, but rebooting is usually easier.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Searching a bit more around the web, In this [archlinux forum post](https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=187411) is said restarting, and it worked.

I just wonder why it did...